# Gembox software can't change Font Name and/or Font Size

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2015, xlsx, gembox-spreadsheet

Using [GemBox](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/) to take an existing .xlsx excel file to populate with data and save it to an .xlsx file.

The issue I am having is this when trying to set the font name and font size using documentation on Gembox website I am getting the following results.

[image: Error when Excel file is open]

[image: Data inside the Excel file]

Here is how I am setting font name

```
.Style.Font.Name = "Calibri";
.Style.Font.Size = 8;
```

Can change any other style except when changing Font Name or Font Size I get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that a Size property is in twip units (1/20th of a point), see the [Size property's help page](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/help/html/P_GemBox_Spreadsheet_ExcelFont_Size.htm).
Can you try setting its value to 8 * 20, does this solve your issue?

In case it does not then can you send us your file by [submitting a support ticket](https://support.gemboxsoftware.com/new-ticket).

Comment: "Size property is in twip units (1/20th of a point)" thank you for point it out. Yes, it works as expected now.